# Moongose, expressjs and node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-webkit

I'm building an app using node-webkit, based on expressjs and mongoose. I'm new to basically all of this.

I've got a mongoDb hosted online and i'm try to use it in my app, but i'm missing something

I created in model folder db.js, where i connect with the db

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@ds012345.mlab.com:port/mydb') //this isn't the real link
```

then my model, clients.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var clientSchema = new Schema ({
            name: String,
            //other fields


});

var client =  mongoose.model('client', clientSchema);
module.exports = client;
```

Then, in my app.js

```
var db = require('./model/db')
```

I'm also using routes, so in my index.js i got

```
var client = require('../model/clients')
```

But i cannot use any function (save, find, ecc.), i can just create models.

I think I'm not connecting in the right way all the modules, i was previously using diskdb and i connected to it in my index.js, but i tried in the same way and it doesn't work anyway.
Also, when i build the app, my mongoose connection status is 2.

Comment: what is `ecc`? you should connect to something like this: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things:

what is `ecc`? you should connect to something like this: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');`

`27017` is the default port for MongoDB and `test` is the name of your database. Also make sure you start mongo server with `mongod` then run mongo console `mongo`.

Your field should specify type of the data:

```
var clientSchema = new Schema ({
   name: String,
   age: Number
});
```

So you want to save the document into database:

```
var client = mongoose.model('client', clientSchema);
var data = {
  nome: 'something'
};
var user = new client(data);
user.save(function(err) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

In your route, you can do something like this to query back and send data back to the req:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var clientSchema = require('../models/clientSchema');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  UserSchema.find({} , function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.render('index', {
      data: data
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: ecc is simply my server address with username and password, sorry i put it in apexes so it seems like i really put ecc (i use mlab.com as host)
Also, the schema is correct i just didn't put all my fields. In fact, if i simply create a new model and send it as res, it works, i just can't save or query the db

Comment: How do you save and query the db? @Sgarro

Comment: var data = {nome: 'something'}  
var user = new client(data);  
user.save(function (err) {  
   if (err)  
   res.send(err)  
  else  
    res.send('saved')  
 });
if only create the data and put a res.send(user) instead of the function, it shows me the models with the id, if i put even a console.log('something') in the function save, it won't show anything and in fact the page won't load (sorry for the formatting, i can't make it work) @Bun

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but sadly it didn't work
I've tried a simple test.js, like this
https://jsfiddle.net/m6us802m/
and it worked (both saving and query), but when i try to use it in my app i can't make it work.
I use routes from app.js so it looks like this
https://jsfiddle.net/Sgarro/v1aacdLe/
And my index.js looks like this
https://jsfiddle.net/Sgarro/L1h3dwbs/

I've even tried putting the connection to the database and the model declaration directly in my index.js and it didn't work. @Bun